# regex too longwinded and multiline issues

Tags: ruby, regex

im trying to change text to go from this:

> \v 1 something \f + \xo footnote one \f* whatever \x + \xo footnote two \x* more text \f + \xo footnote three \f* blah blah blah \x + \xo footnote four \x*
>   \v 2 something \x + \xo footnote one \x*

to this:

> \v 1 something \f * \xo footnote one \f* whatever \x ** \xo footnote two \x* more text \f *** \xo footnote three \f* blah blah blah \x $ \xo footnote four \x* \v 2 something \x * \xo footnote one \x*

so in each footnote, instead of a '+' each will have the next in the sequence (* ** *** $ $$ $$$ £) but the sequence has to reset when it gets to a new verse (\v) there can be up to 7 occurrences of footnotes between each verse.

i'm new to ruby so i know there's a better way to do this, what i've done is very long winded:

```
file = File.open('input.txt', 'r+')
contents = file.read

reassign = contents.gsub(/(\\v.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+/m, '\1*\3**\5***\7$\9$$')
                   .gsub(/(\\v.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+/m, '\1*\3**\5***\7$')
                   .gsub(/(\\v.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+/m, '\1*\3**\5***')
                   .gsub(/(\\v.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+(.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+/m, '\1*\3**')
                   .gsub(/(\\v.*?(\\x|\\f) )\+/m, '\1*')

new_file = File.open("output.txt", "w+")
new_file.write(reassign)
new_file.close
```

if i don't add the m after the regex search it skips a lot of footnotes longer than one line, but if i add it, it skips over the verses altogether and doesn't reset the sequence

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you first `split('\v')` the string, giving you an array of strings, `map` each of the strings in the resulting array to a string with the footnote symbols replaced with the appropriate strings, then `join('\v')` the strings back together.

**Code**

```
def map_footnote_symbols(str)
  str.split('\v').map do |s|
    t = %w{ * ** *** $ $$ $$$ £ }
    s.gsub(/./) { |c| (c == '+') ? t.shift : c }
  end.join('\v')
end
```

**Example**

```
str = "\v 1 something \f + \xo footnote one \f* whatever " +
      "\x + \xo footnote two \x* more text \f + \xo footnote " +
      "three \f* blah blah blah \x + \xo footnote four \x* \v 2 " +
      "something \x + \xo footnote one \x*"
```

(I've broken the string into pieces so that in can be viewed without having to scroll horizontally.)

```
puts map_footnote_symbols str
  #=> \v 1 something \f * \xo footnote one \f* whatever \x ** \xo |
  #   footnote two \x* more text \f *** \xo footnote three \f* |
  #   blah blah blah \x $ \xo footnote four \x* \v 2 something |
  #   \x * \xo footnote one \x*
```

(I've broken the output string into pieces so that in can be viewed without having to scroll horizontally. The character `|` indicates where I've broken each line.)

**Explanation**

```
a = str.split('\v')
  #=> ["",
  #    " 1 something \\f + \\xo footnote one \\f* whatever \\x + \\xo |
  #      footnote two \\x* more text \\f + \\xo footnote three \\f* |
  #      blah blah blah \\x + \\xo footnote four \\x* ",
  #    " 2 something \\x + \\xo footnote one \\x*"]
```

(Again, I've broken the second string in the array into pieces so that in can be viewed without having to scroll horizontally.)

`map` passes each element of `a` into its block, assigning it to the block variable `s`. The first is:

```
s = ""
```

We then have:

```
t = %w{ * ** *** $ $$ $$$ £ }
  #=> ["*", "**", "***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"] 
b = "".gsub(/./) { |c| (c == '+') ? t.shift : c }
  #=> ""
```

So `""` is (obviously) mapped to `""`. The next element (string) `map` passes into the block is:

```
s = "footnote two \\x* more text \\f + \\xo footnote three \\f* " +
    "blah blah blah \\x + \\xo footnote four \\x* "
```

The regex `/./` causes `gsub` to pass each character of `s` to its block to determine the substituted value. `(c == '+')` is `false` for every character up to the first `+`, so these characters are all left unchanged (i.e., replaced by `c`). The first `+` is replaced by `t.shift`:

```
t = ["*", "**", "***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"] 
t.shift #=> "*"
```

leaving

```
t       #=> ["**", "***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"]
```

The characters up to the next `+` are left unchanged and that `+` is replaced by:

```
t.shift #=> "**"
```

leaving

```
t       #=> ["***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"]
```

and so on. As a result:

```
c = a.map do |s|
  t = %w{ * ** *** $ $$ $$$ £ }
  s.gsub(/./) { |c| (c == '+') ? t.shift : c }
end
  #=> ["",
  #    " 1 something \\f * \\xo footnote one \\f* whatever \\x ** \\xo |
  #    footnote two \\x* more text \\f *** \\xo footnote three \\f* |
  #    blah blah blah \\x $ \\xo footnote four \\x* ",
  #    " 2 something \\x * \\xo footnote one \\x*"]
```

All that remains is to reassemble the string:

```
c.join('\v')
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has really helped. i thought iterating could only occur after a function like `.map` or `.each`. also this might seem like a really stupid question but what does the `: c`part of `t.shift : c`do? why is it needed?

Comment: `str.gsub(/./)` passes each character of `str` into it's block (because the regex `/./` matches every single character). The block variable `c` is assigned the value of that character. The block calculates a value that is to be substituted for `c` in the string.  `(c == '+') ? t.shift : c`, which is called a [ternary operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/The-Ternary-Or-Conditional-Operator.htm), is the same as `if (c == '+'); t.shift; else; c; end`. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) Suppose `str = "a+"`. `"a"` is passed to the block and `c = "a"`. `("a" == '+')` is `false`, so `"a"` is replaced by  `"a"` (i.e., left unchanged). Next, `c = "+"`. As `("a" == '+')` is `true`, `"+"` is replaced by  `t.shift => ["*", "**", "***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"].shift => "*"`, leaving `t => ["**", "***", "$", "$$", "$$$", "£"]`.

Comment: ah i see thanks, i tried changing what 'c' matches to a regex, so `s.gsub(/./) { |c| (c == /\d/) ? t.shift : c}` but it doesn't seem to work, i thought the concept would be the same?

Comment: `c == /\d/` is `true` if `c` equals the regular expression `/\d/`, which clearly is not what you want. If you want to use a regex there you would write `c =~ /^\+$/` (or `c =~ /^\+$/`) , where `^` and `$` are beginning and ending of string "anchors". I think you'll agree `c == '+'` is simpler.

Comment: ah right thanks, yes it is simpler i was just thinking about using regex for other search and replaces i may need to do in the future. thanks so much much you've really helped